# codeigniter build a calculator

Tags: php, codeigniter, calculator

I am trying to build a calculator in PHP which will go into a Codeigniter controller. I have a form in html which gets the numbers.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="calc.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="num1">
        <input type="text" name="num2">
        <input type="text" name="num3">
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate">

        <?php echo form_close();?>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a formula that the calculator will operate on which I have tried to layout in the on the calc.php page.

```
if (isset($_POST['value']))
{
    $num1 = $_POST["num1"];
    $num2 = $_POST["num2"];
    $num3 = $_POST["num3"];
}


function calculate()
{ 
    $c = $num1/50;

    $b = $num2/12;

    $s = $num3/5;

    $p = $c + $b - $s;

    if($s > 4)
    {
        $s= 4;
    }
}


    echo $c." + ".$b." - ".$s = ";
    echo $p;
```

I do not think I am doing this quite right. all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Like why would you remove the accepted answer mark? :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things wrong:

1. You are not actually calling your function;
2. You are not returning anything from your function (not strictly necessary but it seems appropriate here);
3. You are using variables in the function that are not defined in the function scope.

Check the manual for more information about [functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) and [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: I will go to the links and study what you are saying thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed some code for you, hope it can help.

```
function calculate($num1, $num2, $num3)
{ 
   $data = array() ;

   $data['c'] = $num1 / 50;
   $data['b'] = $num2 / 12;
   $data['s'] = $num3 / 5;
   $data['p'] = $data['c'] + $data['b'] - $data['s'];

    if($data['s'] > 4)
    {
        $data['s']= 4;
    }
    return $data ;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['value'])) //Additional checks should be done tho.
{
    $num1 = $_REQUEST["num1"];
    $num2 = $_REQUEST["num2"];
    $num3 = $_REQUEST["num3"];

    $data = calculate($num1, $num2, $num3) ;
    echo "{$data['c']} + {$data['b']} - {$data['s']} = {$data['p']}" ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you your code looks a lot better than mine and makes sense to use an array for this.

Answer (score 0):

First off I want to talk everyone who contributed and answer to my question. I used the example Jari had given me, many thanks and I modified it some for my needs in the calc. area.

```
    <?php
    //var_dump ($data['c']);

function calculate($num1, $num2, $num3)
{ 
   $data = array() ;

   $data['c'] = $num1 / 50;
   $data['b'] = $num2 / 12;
   $data['s'] = $num3 / 5;
   $data['p'] = $data['c'] + $data['b'] - $data['s'];


    return $data;


}

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'calc') 
{
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST["num2"];
    $num3 = $_POST["num3"];

    if($num3 > 4)
    {
        $num3 = 4;
    }

    $data = calculate($num1, $num2, $num3);
    $formula = "{$data['c']} + {$data['b']} - {$data['s']} = {$data['p']}";


    echo $data['p'];

}
```

by moving the if statement from above the return and replaced under my post statements. Which help clear up a problem I was having. I then used the advice of jeroen and did some study and created the form page as thus and now it is all working as I needed it to.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3><?php echo (isset($formula)) ? $formula : "Formula Calculator"; ?></h3>
        <form action="calc.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="num1">
            <input type="text" name="num2">
            <input type="text" name="num3">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="calc">    
        </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Again thank you for all of the help and that is what I did to design the calculator that I needed.